# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found while installing Brave Browser

Tags: curl, ubuntu-18.04, openpgp, brave-browser

`curl -s --no-check-certificate https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com/brave-core-nightly.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-prerelease.gpg add -`

I've used this command during the installation of [Brave Browser](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux) but i got this error ***gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found***

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The topic is old, but I will still give you an answer. As far as I know, this is because we are referring to a non-existent file. You can try installing brave in this way:

```
sudo snap install brave
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. After trying to figure out for some time I just found the file doesn't exist. You can resolve this issue by following these commands below

--------------- To install Snap-Store if you haven't ---------------

```
    sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install snapd
    sudo snap install snapd
```

--------------- After that install brave from snap ---------------

```
    sudo snap install brave
```